# Has anyone ever added google pay to a cybersource integration in shopify plus

Tags: shopify, google-pay, cybersource

Cybersource is the payment provider for my Shopify plus store. Within that I have payment methods which include VISA/Mastercard/Applepay. Google pay should also be available here but doesn't exist in the list of options. I can't believe Cybersource doesn't support Googlepay. When I have asked Cybdersource they say that the integration is managed by Shopify, but Shopify tell me I should use ShopifyPay if I want to have GooglePay, I can't believe this, it seems more likely that someone needs to refresh the API to make G-pay appear in the list of options.... does anyone have experience of this?

Thanks so much

I have been bouncing between Shopify help and Cybersource help they both just say it's down to the other.

Comment: BTW, it's generally more appropriate to ask "how do I X?" instead of "has anyone ever done X?" -- write in the form of a FAQ entry, not a forum post. Answering "has anyone ever done X?" doesn't address your _real_ question, which is presumably about a specific issue _you_ had trying to do X.

Answer (score 0):

Cybersource does support Google pay, their API’s can facilitate any Google pay, Apple Pay, PayPal transaction. Shopify chose not to allow Google pay with their cybersource plug in shopify created to force you to switch to shopifys gateway